# How to find the Jacobian of my function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following function in Matlab:

```
f = @(x)[x(1,:)+2*x(2,:)+x(3,:);x(1,:).^3+x(2,:).^2+3*x(3,:)]
```

How can I find the Jacobian matrix of this function in Matlab?

I have tried using the function jacobian, but I don't get it to work for this specific function. Can someone help me with the correct arguments?

Comment: I think you are looking for jacobian which computes the partial derivative for specified function and variable: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jacobian.html?refresh=true

Comment: I have tried using this function, but I don't know what v is, the second argument, for my function? I tried to call:

    jacobian(f,x), but it doesn't work. Can you help me with it?

Comment: `v` is the vector of variables by which the vector function `f` is derived. You can't compute the jacobian of an anonymous function, you need to use the Symbolic Math Toolbox and create symbolic variables with `syms` for that. Look at the examples given in the documentation (`doc symbolic/jacobian`).

Comment: Even if I first write: sym x, and then jacobian(f,x) I get the error:
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Invalid input. 'expression' is expected. [line 1,
col 23]

Error in sym/jacobian (line 34)
Jsym = mupadmex('symobj::jacobian',F.s,x.s);

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just told you that you can't compute the jacobian of an anonymous function like you tried in your question. Look at the examples in the documentation! You'd probably need to do something like `syms x y z` and then `jacobian([x+2*y+z, x^3+y^2+3*z], [x,y,z])`, which I can't try since I don't have the Symbolic Math Toolbox.

Comment: @Amir:  The addition of these tags to a lot of questions is currently [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314976/1079354).  It'd be good if you weighed in on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @dasdingonesin already wrote, you need to use the symbolic toolbox like this:

```
syms x y z;
f = [x+2*y+z, x^3+y^2+3*z];
gradf = jacobian(f, [x,y,z])
```

This results in:

```
gradf =

[     1,   2, 1]
[ 3*x^2, 2*y, 3]
```

By the way: If you need the jacobian in a solver, you can convert that symbolic function back into a regular MATLAB function using `matlabFunction`. There is also a nice tutorial about this topic [available](http://.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/using-symbolic-mathematics-with-optimization-toolbox-solvers.html).